# LWC making SOSL query do not work

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components

I created a method for making a SOSL query. I am trying to use it inside an LWC component. I couldn't figure out how I can configure this .js file for lwc. Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Here is my method in accountController class:

```
  @AuraEnabled
public static List<List<sObject>> searchTerms(List<String> termList) {

List<<List<sObject>> result = new List <List<sObject>> ();
for (String term : termList){
result.addAll([FIND :term IN ALL FIELDS RETURNING Account (Name), Contact (FirstName, LastName) ]) ;
} return result;
}
```

Here is the js file that I couldn't make it work as I expected:

```
import { LightningElement } from 'lwc';
import searchTerms from '@salesforce/apex/AccountController.searchTerms';
export default class Wireornek2 extends LightningElement {
    
    termListWord; 
    accounts;
    error;
  
    handleInput(event){
        this.termListWord=event.target.value;
    }

   
    handleGetAccount(){
        searchTerms({termList: this.termListWord})
            .then((result) => {
                this.accounts = result[0];
                this.error = undefined; 
            })
            .catch((error) =>{
                this.error = error;
                this.accounts = undefined;
            }); 
            
    }
}
```

here is the HTML file that I use:

```
<template>
    <lightning-card title="Search Account">
        <lightning-input type="text" onchange={handleInput}></lightning-input>
   
        <lightning-button label="Get Account" onclick={handleGetAccount}>></lightning-button>
      
        <ul>
            <template for:each={accounts} for:item="w">
               
                <li key={w.Id}>
                Name: {w};
                   
                </li>

            </template>

        </ul>


    </lightning-card> 
</template>
```

Comment: Here the imported method name is different from the variable, so instead of `searchTerms` use `getAccounts`

Comment: And I don't see any uses of `handleGetAccount`, I guess you are triggering this from html button.

Comment: `termListWord` doesn't seem to be like it could be a list of values. We're just missing too much information to help you. What does your template/html look like?

Comment: Right, I am using an html button to trigger this. Thank you for your previous comment I changed getAccounts to searchTerms. Because that is my method name. But again that didn't help.

Comment: Ok let me add html as well.

Comment: @sfdcfox you are right about termListWord. I couldn't figure out how I can add a list item as an input. Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
this.termListWord=event.target.value;
```

Should be:

```
this.termListWord=[event.target.value];
```

This will put the data into the correct format for you to call your searchTerms method.